# How to monitor mongo db replica status and reconfiguring repluica

Tags: mongodb

We are using mongodb cluster with set of 3 members , and all consumers are able to read/write data.

Use mongo.conf file to create cluster && configure replica set, which are executed in ansible script as part of system restart.

Our system does heavy writes/read operation on mongo clusters ,and sometime replica get broken.

Then it is no longer feasible to restore replica without deleting data from one of the corrupted server.
Here are my queries:

1. what is better way to notify when replica is broken using script/some code?We can not use Mongo atlas 
   etc.
2. What is efficient way to restore data on corrupted member.

Comment: What does "replica get broken" mean?

Answer (score 1):

> What is better way to notify when replica is broken using script/some code?

Use the [replSetGetStatus](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/replSetGetStatus/#replsetgetstatus) database command.

You can run this command from any driver or the shell.  Among other things, it returns the state (primary/secondary/startup/recovery/unreachable) and last applied operation time for each member.

> What is efficient way to restore data on corrupted member.

Check out the docs for a few options: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/resync-replica-set-member/#resync-a-member-of-a-replica-set